# Difficulty resolving specific host 'www.xyx.app' in Flutter HTTP request, only in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart, http, dns

I am encountering an issue with Flutter's HTTP package when making a POST request to 'https://www.xyz.app/api/login'. The error message is specific to debug mode:

> SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'www.xyz.app' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))

This issue is observed only in debug mode, as it works perfectly fine after building the APK. Other hostnames like google.com or dummy APIs also work without any problems in debug mode.

Also This issue is specific to certain internet connections.

```
async {
    try {
        final response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse('https://www.xyz.app/api/login'),
            body: {"mobile": phoneNumber, "password": password},
        );

        print(response);
        print(response.headers);
        print(response.statusCode);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Successful login
            final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
            return responseData;
        } else {
            // Handle error cases
            throw Exception('Failed to login');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        throw Exception(e);
    }
}
```

## Troubleshooting steps taken:

- Verified the internet connection and it's active.
- Checked DNS resolution for 'www.xyz.app' – some networks fail to resolve.
- Switched to Google DNS and Cloudflare DNS, but the issue persists.
- Confirmed that other hostnames like google.com work on the same networks.
- Noted that the issue is specific to debug mode; after building the APK, it works fine.

## Additional Information:

- This issue is specific to certain networks; on others, it works perfectly fine.
- Using Flutter version 3.1.3.